# OpenGL translation before and after a rotation

Tags: opengl, coordinate-transformation, opengl-compat

The following is code (taken from http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) regarding how to draw a robot's arm and shoulder and rotating them by some user input:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef (-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef ((GLfloat) shoulder, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0);
        glutWireCube (1.0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef ((GLfloat) elbow, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef (2.0, 0.4, 1.0);
        glutWireCube (1.0);
    glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();  

glutSwapBuffers();
```

I understand the code for drawing the shoulder and rotating it.  For the shoulder: first we translate it one unit back along the x-axis so that when we do the rotation, it rotates along the origin as a pivot.  Then we translate it back (forward one unit on the x-axis).  This transformation will be applied to the cube that has been scaled.

Now, my question is for the elbow.  Why is there a translation forward on the x-axis both before and after the rotate?

Comment: first, thank you for replying.  I understand this now.  But my question then is, why did we first move the elbow forward one unit along the axis (before the rotate).  Why did we not move the elbow first one unit to the left as we did the shoulder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now, my question is for the elbow. Why is there a translation forward on the x-axis both before and after the rotate?

If you want to imagine how the matrix operations change the model, then you need to "read" the operations in the reverse order.
This is, because the current matrix of the matrix stack is multiplied by the matrix which is specified by the new operation and the matrices are stored in column-major order (fixed function pipeline).

Start with the elbow cube

```
glutWireCube(1.0f);
```

[image: arm 01]

Scale the elbow

```
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(2.0f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
glutWireCube(1.0f);
glPopMatrix();
```

[image: arm 02]

Move it to the right

```
glTranslatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

[image: arm 03]

Rotate the elbow

```
glRotatef(45.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

[image: arm 04]

Move the rotated elbow to the right

```
glTranslatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

[image: arm 05]

Draw the shoulder cube

```
glutWireCube(1.0f);
```

[image: arm 06]

Scale the shoulder

```
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(2.0f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
glutWireCube(1.0f);
glPopMatrix();
```

[image: arm 07]

Move the arm (elbow and shoulder) to the right

```
glTranslatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

[image: arm 08]

Rotate the arm

```
glRotatef(-15.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

[image: arm 09]

Move the arm to its final position (to the left)

```
glTranslatef(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

[image: arm 10]