# How to use hierarchy on openGL

Tags: opengl, rotation, draw, hierarchy

How to create some kind of "arm", using sphere as joint (shoulder, elbow, wrist) and ellipsoid as bone (forearm, arm, fingers)?
the shoulder is the root, it all can move like real life arms..

Comment: In general this question is off-topic, because it is too broad and it is unclear what you're asking. But if you use [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) (not recommended) then see [OpenGL Arm that rotates shoulder and elbow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652098/opengl-arm-that-rotates-shoulder-and-elbow.)

Comment: It sounds like you want to use implicit functions to define a model, but with my little experience, I would argue that you would be better off implementing skeletal animations with openGL (have a look at ogldev's 38th tutorial), that way you can do all the animating in a 3D creation software like Blender, export it to dae and you could animate the bone movement in the code.